# R.Java is missing from my project and will not regenerate

Tags: java, android, eclipse, r.java-file

I've began making a new project and just as I was linking my buttons to the java I noticed my R would not resolve and come to find out that my R.java file is not there. I've looked at other questions like this and they say to clean the project which I have done and it still does not work. Here is my code from the pages where it wont resolve. Thanks!

Invoice Java

```
package com.invoice;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class InvoiceActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);
        Thread logoTimer = new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                try{
                    sleep(5000);
                    Intent menuIntent = new Intent("com.invoice.MENU");
                    startActivity(menuIntent);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                finally{
                    finish();
                }
            }
        };
        logoTimer.start();
    }
}
```

Job.java

```
package com.invoice;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Job extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.job);
    }
}
```

menu.java

```
package com.invoice;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class menu extends Activity{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Button job = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
        job.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent("com.invoice.job"));

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
    }
}
```

Comment: Right click on `Project` Then click `Properties -> Android`. Are any of the API levels checked (Under the `project build target` heading)?

Comment: Yes, The Android 2.3.3 API is checked.

Comment: Are there any red annotations on any of the project files? These can keep the R.java file from being generated.

Comment: does the project compile?

Comment: Are you sure the problem list is empty? Such a thing may happen if you have errors in your resources. If so, they fail to compile, and that prevents R from getting generated. Also ... well, restart Eclipse.

Comment: The thing is that I'm only getting red marks on the R. and then the rest is fine and the project will not load/compile on emulator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have an error in an xml file. R.java will not be generated if there are xml errors. Look through you Manifest.xml and all your layout, values, and any other xml files in res.

Once you have found and fixed the error, clean the project.

Comment: Thank You, I found an invalid PNG file in the Resource folder that was screwing it up.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have problem in resource folder, first solve that error.numeric name of image can generate errors.After solving the errors just clean your project or  Build your Project. R.java build again if error is fixed.